# How do I run a python code on a cloud service to automate it's run for 5 days

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, automation

I am working on a web scraping project using python and an API
I want the python script to be ran everyday for 5 days for 12 hours as a job
I don't want to keep my system alive to either do it in CMD or in Jupyter so I was looking for a solution wherein any cloud service would help me automate the process

Comment: Side-question: Why do you wish to limit to a 12-hour job? Is it because that is sufficient time to complete a daily job and each day scrapes the same data? Where are you storing your data? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to write a web scraper in Python, and run it on an AWS Lambda, which is essentially a serverless function with no underlying ops to manage. Depending on your use case, you could either perform some action based on the contents of that page data, or you could write the result out to S3 as a file.

To have your function execute in a recurring fashion, you can then set your AWS Lambda event trigger to be a CloudWatch event (in this case, some recurring timer at whatever frequencies/times you'd like, such as once each hour for a 12 hour window during Mon-Fri).

This is typically going to be an easier approach when compared to spinning up a virtual server (EC2 instance), and managing a persistent process that could error during waits/operation for any number of reasons.